# Recursively cut file suffix in subfolders

Tags: bash, mv

I have a lot of directories with files in it:

> large_fffd612bdc3fab_main

I want cut suffix `large_` from all files in directories recursively and get name `fffd612bdc3fab_main`

I use this command and it works with files located in directory

```
for f in `find . -depth -type f -name large_*`; do mv $f $(echo $f | cut -c1-); done;
```

but when i try to work with subfolders i get such error:

```
mv: './fff97489a19e89_main/large_fff97489a19e89_main' and './fff97489a19e89_main/large_fff97489a19e89_main' are the same file
```

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `-exec` and a sub-shell:

```
find . -name large_\* -exec \
  sh -c 'f=$(basename "$1"); d=$(dirname "$1"); echo mv "$1" "$d/${f#large_}"' _ {} \;
```

The `echo` in there is just for testing.
After confirming that the output looks as you expect,
you can either remove the `echo` and rerun,
or simply pipe this to another `sh` (unless the filenames contain special characters, in which case piping to `sh` won't work, but removing `echo` will).

This is better than the for-loop you're trying to write for several reasons:

- A for-loop over the output of `find` is not safe in general, and a bad habit
- The `echo ... | cut` is wasteful, slow. Variable substitution with `${name#large_}` is fast

Comment: Tip: `sh -c '...{}...'` is [not safe](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2156) in general either. Consider rewriting to `sh -c '...$1...' _ {}`

Comment: Thanks a lot gents !!